# Javascript rewrite width, height in URL

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have one problem, in the iframe url I need to have width and height, source: `<iframe src="http://yzs.com/xxxx-720x405.html" width="720" height="405"></iframe>` in the certain resolution ( for example: on the mobile ) it is not correctly shown so its longer then display. My question is: is it possible somehow with javascript rewrite a width and height ( in URL ) from a certain resolution?

Comment: Yes it is possible, what have you tried?

Comment: What is your actual problem here? Sounds like you'd like to include this information to the search string of the URL, but you don't know how to get the information, or how to add it to the URL (=== `src` of the iframe)?

Comment: I haven't tried anything. I don't know nothing in this way of javascript.. I just want to change the width and height of the video player because I am coding responsive for my website and video players are just bigger than my display on the phone because it has fixed width and height in the URL..So I want to somehow change width and height in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at this

http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/newtech3.shtml

```
var scr = window.screen
var l = scr.availwidth
var h = scr.availHeight
```

will give you access to the available height and width on screen